# React webpackage webpack-obfuscator: Cannot find module 'object-assign'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'am tryng to use a webpack-obfuscator inside a React project. I added the configuration in order to obfucate the source code, but not the imported librariers, but I get this error message while luncing the command to create the webpack:

```
npm run dev
```

webpack Cannot find module 'object-assign'

Below the configuration I have for this project:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "xyz",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/apps/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@date-io/date-fns": "^1.3.13",
    "@date-io/moment": "^2.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.39",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "^3.2.10",
    "apexcharts": "^3.28.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "crypto-random-string": "^4.0.0",
    "cypress": "^9.1.1",
    "date-fns": "^2.14.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.28",
    "fetch-retry": "^3.1.0",
    "i18next": "^21.5.4",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.2",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.3.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "mui-datatables": "^2.15.0",
    "multimatch": "^6.0.0",
    "npm": "^7.16.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-alert": "^7.0.3",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.3.9",
    "react-async": "^10.0.0",
    "react-avatar": "^3.9.0",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-filter-box": "^3.4.2",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.17.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.14.3",
    "react-image-mapper": "0.0.15",
    "react-lineto": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-number-format": "^4.4.1",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.18",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-split-pane": "^0.1.89",
    "react-svg-pathline": "^0.5.0",
    "react-youtube": "^7.11.2",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.7.0-dev"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "dev": "webpack serve",
    "production": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "csv-loader": "^3.0.5",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "interpolate-html-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "javascript-obfuscator": "^4.0.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.6.1",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "object-assign": "^4.1.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.10.1",
    "webpack-obfuscator": "^3.5.1",
    "xml-loader": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```json
{
 "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```js
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require("interpolate-html-plugin");
const WebpackObfuscator = require('webpack-obfuscator');

const webpack = require('webpack');
//const multimatch = require('multimatch');

const publicUrl = process.env.PUBLIC_URL;

module.exports = {
 mode: "development",
 entry: {
    app: "./src/index.js"
 },
 devtool: 'source-map', //'eval',
 devServer: {
  
    static: {
        directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        staticOptions: {
          index: false
        } 
      },
      liveReload: false,
      compress: true,
      port: 80,
      open: true,
      hot: false,
      client: false,
      historyApiFallback: false

 },
 output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: "/"
  },
 resolve: {
   extensions: [".wasm", ".mjs", ".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".json"], // ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],
   alias: {
     '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src') // shortcut to reference src folder from anywhere
    
   },
    fallback: {
        crypto: require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
        assert: require.resolve('assert'),
        console: require.resolve('console-browserify'),
        constants: require.resolve('constants-browserify'),
        domain: require.resolve('domain-browser'),
        events: require.resolve('events'),
        http: require.resolve('stream-http'),
        https: require.resolve('https-browserify'),
        os: require.resolve('os-browserify/browser'),
        path: require.resolve('path-browserify'),
        punycode: require.resolve('punycode'),
        process: require.resolve('process/browser'),
        querystring: require.resolve('querystring-es3'),
        stream: require.resolve('stream-browserify'),
        string_decoder: require.resolve('string_decoder'),
        sys: require.resolve('util'),
        timers: require.resolve('timers-browserify'),
        tty: require.resolve('tty-browserify'),
        url: require.resolve('url'),
        vm: require.resolve('vm-browserify'),
        zlib: require.resolve('browserify-zlib'),
        isomorphic: require.resolve('isomorphic-fetch'),
        log: false,
        object_assign: require.resolve('object-assign'),
        scheduler: require.resolve('scheduler')
    }
 
 },
 module: {
   rules: [
    
     { // config for es6 jsx
       test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: {
         loader: "babel-loader"
       }      
     },
     { // config for sass compilation
       test: /\.scss$/,
       use: [
         {
           loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
         },
         'css-loader',
         {
           loader: "sass-loader"
         }
       ]
     },
     {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          // [style-loader](/loaders/style-loader)
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          // [css-loader](/loaders/css-loader)
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true
            }
          },
          // [sass-loader](/loaders/sass-loader)
          { loader: 'sass-loader' }
        ]
      },
     { // config for images
       test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
       type: 'asset/resource',
       exclude: /node_modules/,
       use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'] 
     },
     { // config for fonts
       test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/,
       use: [
         {
           loader: 'file-loader',
           options: {
             outputPath: 'fonts',
           }
         }
       ],
     },
     {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
      
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        
        exclude: [ 
            //path.resolve(__dirname, 'content.js') 
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/react/index.js')
        ],
      
        enforce: 'post',
        //exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: { 
            loader: WebpackObfuscator.loader, 
            options: {
                rotateStringArray: true
            }
        }
      }
   ],
   noParse: [require.resolve('typescript/lib/typescript.js')]
 },
 plugins: [
  
  new WebpackObfuscator ({
    rotateStringArray: true
  }),
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    process: 'process/browser',
  }),
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({ // plugin for inserting scripts into html
    template: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/index.html"),
    inject: true,
    PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl   
   }),
   new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ // plugin for controlling how compiled css will be outputted and named
     filename: "css/[name].css",
     chunkFilename: "css/[id].css"
   }),
   new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
    PUBLIC_URL: '' 
  })
 
 ]
};
```

Can anybody help on this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try in your terminal

```
npm install object-assign
```